# Publicando aplicação asp.net no IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, url, iis

Estou tentando publicar minha aplicação num servidor windows server 2012 com IIS 8. Fiz o passo a passo de ir em "Site -> Add Website" preencher com as coordenadas, caminhos e etc. Fiz o deploy na devida pasta padrão "Inetpub -> wwwroot", porém obtenho o seguinte erro ao testar no browse do próprio servidor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha aplicação é windows authentication. A conexão, url, Ip estão ok. Local eu consigo acessar normalmente a aplicação e banco que estão em outro servidor, mas no IIS ao publicar não consigo. Esse erro se dá quando eu deixo 'Enabled' para Anonymous Authentication e 'Disabled' para Windows Authentication. Quando eu inverto a autenticação surge então o pop up para eu passar minhas credenciais de logon, mas não aceita nenhum login que eu tento e após 3 tentativas dá o erro:

**HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.**

Constatei que desabilitando a windows authentication e na url, passando o nome de uma view depois (meusite.br/nomedeumaview) a página aparece mas não carrega os meus dados que deveriam ser carregados já que minha aplicação é windows authentication.

Meu web config e string de conexão:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="BancoContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=BancoContext-20140116130500; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|BancoContext-20140116130500.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>

<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Banco.Business.CustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
  </roleManager>

 <authentication mode="Windows" /> 

 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />


 <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>

<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
  </pages>
 </system.web>

  public const string CONNECTION_STRING = @"Data Source=Servidor;Initial Catalog=Banco;User Id=integracao;Password=00000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
  public const string DEVELOPMENT_CONNECTION_STRING = @"Data Source=Servidor;Initial Catalog=Banco;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
```

Comment: Tem que habilitar a Pesquisa de Diretório (Browsing) para ver arquivos quando não tem Documento Padrão. http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Eu já habilitei. Criei também a página defaul mas continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você definiu qual Application Pool pra esse website?

Comment: Já tentei a default, a que se cria com o mesmo nome do website e com a .NET v4.5 @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: @Tony constatei que passando a URL mais o nome de uma view (minha-pagina.br/nomedaview) abre na página correspondente do meu programa, só que sem a autenticação com os dados do usuário como deveria aparecer.

Comment: E a página inicial não abre embora já tenha colocado o nome dela em 'Default Document'

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez dei uma editada na pergunta.